# Rabl conforming to jsonapi.org

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rabl

I'm having a lot of trouble getting rabl to conform the the jsonapi.org spec. I have seen the wiki entry on github regarding this (https://github.com/nesquena/rabl/wiki/Conforming-to-jsonapi.org-format) but I dont understand how to get multiple root level nodes in rabl and still have collections work. The wiki entry on collections says this should work

```
collection [@post] => :posts
attributes :id, :title
child @post => :links do
  node(:author)   { @post.author_id }
  node(:comments) { @post.comments_ids }
end
```

which for single root documents it does, but as soon as I try to add a `meta` or `links` to the root of the document as declared in the jsonapi.org spec, those nodes are appended to the existing collection node. Here is my rabl_init.rb

```
require 'rabl'
Rabl.configure do |config|
  config.cache_sources = Rails.env != 'development'
  config.include_child_root = false
  config.include_json_root = false
end
```

I would like json that looks like this:

```
{
 "links": {
 "posts.comments": "http://example.com/posts/{posts.id}/comments"
},
 "posts": [{
    "id": "1",
     "title": "Rails is Omakase"
  }, {
    "id": "2",
    "title": "The Parley Letter"
 }] 
}
```

is Rabl capable of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```rb
object false

node(:links) do
  {"posts.comments" => "http://example.com/posts/{posts.id}/comments"}
end

child(@posts) do
  attributes :id, :title
end
```